# Build a Context-Free Grammar for a given language

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

$L_1 = \{a^n b^m a\mid n\geqslant1,m\geqslant0\} $

I can't really seem to figure the list of productions for this simple language, I know I have to write the non-terminals, but how do I decide which is the starting point S? And then how do I continue?

Comment: Sorry, did you forget $m$ somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it's _b_ to the power of _m_

Answer (score 1):

!!**Answer to the original question for $L= \{a^n b^n a | n\geq1, m\geq0\}$**!!

The starting point is some non-terminal symbol you define as such, let us call it S.

Now we observe that the numbers of a and b in $a^n b^n$ must be equal. The obvious way to achieve this is to generate them in pairs. Because we do not want them mixed, the non-terminal must be inbetween them: $A \rightarrow aAb$.

To generate the final $a$ we use $S\rightarrow Aa$.

For terminating $A \rightarrow ab$.

Comment: For the changed question: $S\rightarrow aA, A\rightarrow aA, A\rightarrow B, B\rightarrow bB, B\rightarrow a$; this is even regular.

Comment: What if it was $a^n b^m$? Plus, why do we have to write for the final _a_ $Aa$ - what's that _A_ for?

Comment: The A signals that we have already written the final a and are in the phase of generating pairs. Because the nonterminal has to be between the a and b, we generate the final a first, because later we cannot do so "through" the block of b. Of course, there are different ways to do this.

Comment: Ah, I see, and is this also in the Chomsky normal form?

Comment: No, it is not in CNF. Use something like $A_1\rightarrow AA_2, A_2\rightarrow A_1B, A\rightarrow a, B\rightarrow b$ instead of $A\rightarrow aAb$; the latter has the problem that its right hand side is size 3 and mixes nonterminals and terminals. Also the other rules have to me modified.